# How to query all entries with a value in a nested bigquery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I generated a BigQuery table using an existing BigTable table, and the result is a multi-nested dataset that I'm struggling to query from. Here's the format of an entry from that BigQuery table just doing a simple `select * from my_table limit 1`:

```
[
  {
    "rowkey": "XA_1234_0",
    "info": {
      "column": [],
      "somename": {
        "cell": [
          {
            "timestamp": "1514357827.321",
            "value": "1234"
          }
        ]
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

What I need is to be able to get all entries from `my_table` where the `value` of `somename` is X, for instance. There will be multiple rowkeys where the `value` of `somename` will be X and I need all the data from each of those rowkey entries.

OR

If I could have a query where rowkey contains X, so to get "XA_1234_0", "XA_1234_1"... The "XA" and the "0" can change but the middle numbers to be the same. I've tried doing a `where rowkey like "$_1234_$"` but the query goes on for over a minute and is way too long for some reason.

I am using standard SQL.

EDIT: Here's an example of a query I tried that didn't work (with error: `Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<timestamp TIMESTAMP, value STRING>>`), but best describes what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_dataset.mytable` where info.field_name.cell.value=12345
```

I want to get all records whose `value` in `field_name` equals some value.

Answer (score 3):

From the [sample Firebase Analytics dataset](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/firebase-analytics-sample-data:android_dataset.app_events_20160607):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.android_dataset.app_events_20160607`
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)
  WHERE key='powers' AND value.value.string_value='20'
)
LIMIT 1000
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT t.*
FROM `my_dataset.mytable` t, 
  UNNEST(info.somename.cell) c
WHERE c.value = '1234'
```

above is assuming specific `value` can appear in each record just once - hope this is a true for you case

If this is not a case - below should make it

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `yourproject.yourdadtaset.yourtable`
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST(info.somename.cell)
  WHERE value = '1234'
)
```

which I just realised pretty much same as Felipe's version - but just using your table / schema

Comment: So I've tried using both queries and, while they run with no errors, the query takes a very long time. I didn't let it complete but it was over 2 minutes and this is much longer than we need, where anything above a few seconds would be too long. I'm thinking this may be inherent to the structure of the data and having to unnest every record is expensive.

Comment: it very much might be because of schema and needs in unnesting. you might try to revisit the schema and make it flatten so for querying purposes. also - do you need `SELECT *` or you can just get few fields in the output - usually it also helps speed up getting result loaded into client